# Football coaching

Tags: football, coaching

I want to be football coach you know like football manager I want to know what should be my first step. well I don't play football in school or college and I am not that good but I like tactics and all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a coach doesn't require to be a good player at all.

The requirements to become a football coach vary, but a bachelor's degree in sport coaching education, physical education, or exercise and sports science is often required.

If you want to become a Pro Coach, then you will need to make bachelor's degree, more than likely. If you are in high school or college, my suggestion would be to "hunt" for a coach's assistant's place for the start, this would not require any degree.

**but you would need skills like:**

- Understanding of the game
- Being a good leader
- Being very detail-oriented
- Being an excellent communicator
- Having physical stamina

Comment: Thanks for your help so I am thinking about to join local football club for some practice and understanding the game